# Django - Configuração do DATABASES

Tags: django, odbc

DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
'**NAME**': 'name',

A string do **ODBC** só excuta com o atributo **DATABASE**, porém o Django só executa com o atributo **NAME**. Como posso resolver este conflito?
Grato!

Answer (score 0):

Adriano, quando vc está configurando no settings o banco de dados conforme ilustrado por vc na pergunta, vc está criando um dicionário que vai representar chave e valor.
Se o atributo DATABASE é necessário vc pode colocá-lo como:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'DATABASE_ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyobdc',
        'DATABASE_NAME': 'name',
        ...
    }
}
```

não se esqueça de fazer a instalação do pyobdc por não ser nativo do django

```
pip install sql_server.pyodbc
```

Comment: a instalação desta está versão é 1.0 só dá suporte para o SQL Server 2000 e 2005, uso o 2017. Instalei pip install sql_server.pyodbc. Para o Django o atributo NAME é obrigatório, para o ODBC é necessário usar DATABASE. Coloquei o atributo DATABASE em  'extra_params': 'DATABASE=XXX'. Não funcionou. Valeu!

Comment: Resolvi colocando: 
'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'extra_params': 'SERVER=Name_SErver;Trusted_Connection=Yes',
        },

Comment: aí sim! adiciona uma resposta detalhando o passo a passo pra resolver esse problema... como ficou o settings, a versão q usou, esses detalhes

Answer (score 0):

Padrão Django:
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
'HOST': 'xxx',
'NAME': 'xxx',
'USER': 'xxx',
'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
'PORT': 'xxx',
'OPTIONS': {
'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
},
},
}

Como o ODBC não reconhecia a chave NAME e o Django DATABASE. Adicionei 'extra_params', utilizando a chave DATABASE
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
'HOST': 'xxx',
'NAME': 'xxx',
'USER': 'xxx',
'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
'PORT': 'xxx',
'OPTIONS': {
'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
'extra_params': 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=xxx;DATABASE=xxx;USER=xxx;PASSWORD=xxx;Trusted_Connection=Yes',
},
},
}